# How can a mudblazor image be scaled to fit entirely within the browser window regardless of browser width and height?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am developing a Blazor server application. I am using the MudBlazor component, MudImage, to display an image. I am attempting to scale the size of the image in a browser based on the browser window size. I have tried:

`<MudImage Fluid="true" Src="@FileToDisplay" Alt="Mony the dog" Elevation="25" Class="rounded-lg" />`

I don't know how to prevent the image height from getting greater than the browser height. As a user changes the size of the browser, the image changes size. If the user increases the width of the browser, the image height increases. The image width is bounded by the browser width, but the image height is not bounded by the browser height. Is there a way to maintain the image aspect ratio and limit the image size to the browser width and height at the same time? This means that the image width would need to stop increasing when the browser width increases enough that the image height would exceed the browser height.

If MudImage does not have a property that would handle this, is there another way (CSS or C#) to handle this?

Comment: Look at the "Image Fit" part of their support page... Your using Fluid.

Comment: Thank you, @Brian_Parker. The Image Fit section of the docs for MudImage is what I started from. Apparently I inadvertently removed `ObjectFit="ObjectFit.Contain"` from the statement. With it included, the behavior is still as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to display the image in the page you can use the viewport height and width CSS property:

```
<MudImage class="myImage" Src="images/sweden.jpg" Elevation="25" />

<style>
    .myImage {
    max-width: 100vw; 
    height: auto;
    max-height:100vh;
    width:auto;
    }
</style>
```

See:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEwRklPfyNXOwSBq

Comment: Many thanks @maciek for your help. In the MudBlazor playground, it works flawlessly. On my end, even with nothing else on the page (I do have `@code`), I do find two things of note: 1) changing the browser width causes the image size to adjust, while changing the browser height does not cause the image size to adjust; and 2) if the browser height is less than the image height and the width is adjusted, the image height continues to increase until it is 100% even though the bottom part of the image is no longer visible.

Comment: I created a new Blazor project with .NET 7 and MudBlazor. Everything looks fine... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRwdRoHC5ao Please ignore the watermark, it was added by the screen capturing software. Is it something like in the video that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, @maciek. I realized that there must be something in my project that overrides the intended behavior. I will have to do what you did - start with a blank slate. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @HamiltonWoods You know you can accept my answer as the correct one by clicking check mark symbol? =D That would make me happy